# Cross-domain tracking URL parameters appearing on sub-domains

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

We're running Google Tag Manager on several domains and several sub-domains and using Cross Domain Tracking and Sub Domain Tracking as detailed in [this Lunametrics blog post](http://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2015/06/16/cross-domain-tracking-with-google-tag-manager/).

As of a few days ago, the cross-domain tracking url parameters (?_ga=) started appearing on sub-domains when clicking from say www.example.com to secure.example.com - which to my understanding it should not be doing.

This is causing havoc to some of our login systems. In this time no changes were published from GTM.

I'm trying to find out from our IT team if they made any server side changes but I'm pretty clueless when it comes to back-end and am hoping some smart people here might be able to make some suggestions as to what is causing GTM to start treating sub-domains as cross-domains.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

For subdomain tracking, You only need to set the Field Name cookieDomain to auto and nothing else. Don't do the rest of steps on the post since that's for tracking different domains. This will remove the (?_ga=) parameters in your url's

If you read the post again you'll find this set of instructions

> IMPORTANT: Before you get started
>
> > If you are trying to track users across many different subsections of a single domain, e.g.:
> >
> > shopping.lunametrics.com
> >
> > www.lunametrics.com
> >
> > admin.lunametrics.com
>
> You are not interested in cross domain tracking, you are interested in subdomain tracking. The best way to accomplish this is to add the ‘cookieDomain’ Field To Set and set it’s value to auto. That will instruct the tracker to make the cookie available to all of the subdomains that it can.

Comment: Hi - thank you for the response. We have both cross-domain tracking and sub-domain tracking, so we're implementing both of these.

The cookieDomain is set to auto.

Comment: the ?_ga= parameters are needed to pass on the user cookie across the different sites so that GA can tell that they're the same visitor and not a new visitor.

Comment: Hi - yep. The problem is it's passing them to the sub domains as well as the other domains. I.e.: it's treating the sub domains like it should be trying to cross domains.

Comment: In the autolink domain don't put "example.com" because GTM would read it as ".example.com" (regex) and it will include all the subdomains of example.com. So be very specific on which domains it will be linked. You can learn more about it here http://www.simoahava.com/analytics/cross-domain-tracking-across-subdomains/

Comment: I want it to include all sub domains of example.com (secure.example.com, admin.example.com) and then cross link to www.othersite.com. The problem remains that it's treating secure.example.com, example.com and admin.example.com as if they're separate domains.

Comment: Ah now I get it! then just put "www.othersite.com" in the autolink domain field. You don't need to put secure.example.com and admin.example.com because the cookiedomain auto would've already taken care of tracking your subdomain.

Comment: Hi - thanks for your continued help. That's fixed it going one way from www.example.com to the sub-domain but when it returns from the sub-domain back to www.example.com, it's adding a cross-domain tag again.

Comment: It seems to work with *.example.com. I'm not sure why this would suddenly need to be rather than just example.com but it works! Thanks for your help.